# Creating VS 2010 executable for Daily Tasks

Tags: c#, visual-studio, executable, scheduled-tasks

I want to create an executable in VS 2010. This executable will be create an excel spreadsheet and will transfer that file via FTP. I want this executable to be fired off via Windows tasks.

What is the best way to accomplish this? Would I create a regular windows form application, dll, or Empty Project, or windows service?

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A plain old console application scheduled with the task scheduler should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the application to run when a computer is turned on but no one is logged in, create a service.  If your application runs only when someone is logged in, but has no UI, use a console application.  If your application runs only when someone is logged in and has a UI, use a Winforms app.

Comment: a scheduled task is created and configured to run with a specific use account and task is executed in a session similar to the one we would have if such account logs in, so a console or windows application started with no UI but a command line parameter to execute something would also work, we use this every day with some legacy windows forms app which show no ui when executed from a task.

Comment: Nice to know that that works.  Good alternative to running a service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the current best practice is, but in our shop we create console applications and use the task scheduler to execute them.

A library (dll) won't be executable from the task scheduler AFAIK, and a WinForms app isn't very useful for any app that runs automatically (i.e.: doesn't require user interaction).

A service would be appropriate for an application that needs to respond to system events/changes when they occur, which doesn't sound like your use case.